# Liferay 7 scheduled journal content does not work

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

intermittently, we see that the scheduled journal articles do not work. At times, it works fine, other times, it shows something like:

[image: Liferay admin panel image]

In the image, you can see that the scheduled article was supposed to appear 2 min ago yet is in "scheduled" status.

I have two questions:

1. Is there any settings we can check to ensure that the scheduled article feature works?
2. Even when the article is approved after some time, it does not show in the asset publisher that should show it based on the article's category. How to achieve it is not just approved, but also is visible?

The time seems to be correctly set based on the fact that it says it should be displayed in "2 min ago"...

EDIT: I also tried setting `journal.article.check.interval=1` which does not help

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, i tried configuring user's timezone and it's work. Please try to configure user's time zone and see.

Thanks